# matplotlib figure canvas name

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a GUI built using PyQt4 where I use matplotlib (FigureCanvas) to plot several plots using multiple canvases (this is intentional rather than using subplots).  for each canvas I use method:

```
self.canvas_xx.mpl_connect('scroll_event', self.on_mouse_scroll)
```

where xx represents the iteration of the canvas to get a signal to perform some action. I want to be able to reference the canvas by its name rather than using:

```
ylabel = event.inaxes.axes.get_ylabel().split(' ')[0]
```

where I use the longer method of referncing the ylabel name of each graph.

I looked under the event method using: dir(event) and there is a method called "canvas", but there is no apparent method to get the name of the canvas.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by name?  You can get a reference to a the canvas object via `event.inaxes.axes.figure.canvas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by name, but you can get a a reference to the `canvas` object via

```
event_canvas = event.inaxes.axes.figure.canvas
```

and canvas events are hashable, so you can use them as keys in a `dict`

```
other_thing = pre_populated_dict[event_canvas]
```

to keep track of what ever other data you want to about a given canvas in your code.

In python there is, in general, not a clean way to get the names of references to an object (it can be done, but you shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks!  What I mean by "name" is that I want to get a reference to the canvas that sent the event (where mouse is currently position).  In other words, I want to know which self.canavsxx sent the event such as:  "self.canvas01" sent event.  But it seems it is not clean way and I will use the "ylabel" of each canvas since they are different.